# directory index of "/var/www/html/domain1/public_html/" is forbidden, server: domain1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain1"

Tags: django, apache, nginx

I have 3 domains 2 of them are reversed proxied to apache with `nginx` for `mod_wsgi` and django usage and the 3rd domain will be nginx.

Both the reversed proxied sites to apache are giving me 403 errors.

Anyone able to help me out here?

Nginx configs:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user              john;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domain1.com;
    #root /var/www/html/domain1.com/public_html;
    return 301 https://domain1.com;

         location ~ /\.ht {
               deny all;

                 }
}


server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        root /var/www/html/domain1.com/public_html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name domain1.com;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain1.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/domain1.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        client_body_buffer_size 1m;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 256 16k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8081;
         }


         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domain2.com;
    #root /var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html;
    return 301 https://domain2.com;

         location ~ /\.ht {

               deny all;

                 }
}

server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        root /var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html;
        index  index.html index.html index.php;
        server_name domain2.com;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain2.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/domain2.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domain3.com;
    #root /var/www/html/domain3.com/public_html;
    return 301 https://domain3.com;

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}

server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        root /var/www/html/domain3.com/public_html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name domain3.com;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain3.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/domain3.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        client_body_buffer_size 1m;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 256 16k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8081;
         }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

---

```
ps -ef|grep nginx
root     29795     1  0 12:13 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
john     29796 29795  0 12:13 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process           
john     29865 29113  0 12:29 pts/2    00:00:00 grep nginx


ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep
root     29795  0.0  0.0 107096  2332 ?        Ss   12:13   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
john     29796  0.0  0.0 109308  5300 ?        S    12:13   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

httpd.conf:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/log 

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ramblr.io/public_html/
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/ramblr.io/public_html/rambler/rambler/wsgi.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess rambler.io python-path=/var/www/html/ramblr.io/public_html/env/lib/pyth$
  WSGIProcessGroup rambler.io
  <Directory "/var/www/html/ramblr.io/public_html/rambler/rambler">
  <IfVersion < 2.3 >
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
   AllowOverride All 
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
  </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion >= 2.3>
   Require all granted
  </IfVersion>
  </Directory>
 <Directory /var/www/html/ramblr.io/public_html/ramble>
 <Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Files>
</Directory>
  ServerAlias ramblr.io
  ServerName ramblr.io
  ServerAdmin johnripper@ramblr.io
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ramblr.io.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ramblr.io.key
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  SecRuleEngine Off
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8081>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.animegrinder.com/public_html/
  <Directory "/var/www/html/test.animegrinder.com/public_html"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
  </Directory> 
  ServerName test.animegrinder.com
  ServerAlias test.animegrinder.com
  ServerAdmin admin@animegrinder.com
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/test.animegrinder.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/test.animegrinder.com.key
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  SecRuleEngine Off
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule security2_module>
   Include crs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf
   Include crs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/base_rules/*.conf
</IfModule>


sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
Listen 127.0.0.1:8081
```